# Migrating Permissions from Gitolite to GitLab

Tags: git, github, gitlab, gitolite

Could someone please help me understand how could we migrate permissions from Gitolite to Gitlab. If my understanding is correct, Gitolite has permissions in terms of RW whereas Gitlab has used descriptive names such as Guest, Developer, etc. So when we import Gitolite repos to Gitlab, I am assuming the permissions do not get migrated. If it is correct, what would be the best way to migrate/map permissions between gitolite and gitlab. Would we need to make groups with permissions manually or via a script. Similarly, would we need to copy over the ssh keys of members for git shell.

Any help would be highly appreciated as I am new to this migration between gitolie and gitlab.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

I guess a solution is to write your own script where you can set your own translation of permissions, something like:
RW --> Developer
R --> Guest
Beware though that by default, gitlab "forces" developers to work on branches by protecting the master branch.

Now your script shall use the gitlab API to set the permissions, but I don't know exactly if it is possible, because I don't know gitlab's API enough. Sorry, not very helpful (esp. for such an old thread), but I guess this looks like the way to do this migration, and this vague answer may still be useful for a future reader to start migrating...